# How to parse Html from a textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html layout which has one text area,the layout is in such a way that the page is divided two parts 1st part consists of a text-area and the 2nd part is empty.i want to ask that is there any way in which i can parse html from a text area and display the result of the html code provided in text-area in the 2nd part. Please help me ...

Comment: read the value, set the innerHTML?

Comment: from what you mean by HTML code? you want to display data of text area at some specific feild?or you want some thing else?

Comment: provide some code.. we do help you with your code, but we don't write it for you

Comment: i mean how can i show the result of html typed in a text box

Comment: My friend what are you using as Java Script?? Plain JS or jQuery or prototype?? We have different ways for all. Which way you want and on what event??So please provide some code so we all can understand.

Comment: note that parsing code entered in a textfield causes security problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></div>
<div id="out"></div>
```

JavaScript ( Using jQuery )

```
$("textarea").on("input propertychange", function(){
    $("#out").html($("textarea").val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fv3X4/)

Comment: that is what i was looking for thanx a lot but if a user  types html and css will it work ??

Comment: @user3148503 yes, it will work.

Comment: <script>
$("textarea").on("input propertychange", function(){
$("#out").html($("textarea").val());
}); </script>
<body>


<div><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></div>
<div id="out"></div>

Comment: @user3148503 You have to include jquery first. Add this line **before** the script tag: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
$("textarea").on("input propertychange", function(){
$("#out").html($("textarea").val());
}); </script>